# Copy file - Access denied

Tags: copy

I have a batch file where I copy file from a different server. I have no issues running it on the server. But when I try to run it from a web application, the file does not copy. I keep getting `access denied` error. I have used `xcopy`, copy and `robocopy`.

I have provided full access to source and destination folder for all users.

No luck. Keep getting the same error :

> copy /y \N01APW280\d$\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\epmsystem1\diagnostics\logs\essbase\essbase_0\app\PLPLAN\PLPLAN.LOG D:\Hyperion\ERPI_Actuals_Load\Logs\

Answer (score 0):

It is rather awkward to try and use a command-line utility, such as copy, from a web app; you should rather be using the programmatic abilities within your web application instead.

Aside from that, you main issue is that web apps are typically executed with very limited privileges, using local machine accounts that have no way of accessing administrative level shares on remote machines such as \N01APW280\d$. Another possible issue is that the local account that is being used by the web app cannot write to D:\Hyperion\ERPI_Actuals_Load\Logs\ folder. And finally, your app may have enough privileges to instantiate an external process such as copy.exe.

Comment: The batch file does a lot of other things. It triggers data loads. It  triggers other batch. But just this copy does not work. It is essential for me to copy the file immediately after the load. So I cannot go out of batch file to copy the file. I am stuck at this once piece.

Comment: First, you will need to know which user account your web app uses, and make sure it can read from the source folder and write to the target folder. One problem would be accessing the remote share, like you're trying to do, because by default web apps use local server accounts which cannot access remote shared folders, unless those shares do not require authentication (i.e. can be accessed by Everyone) In you case you are trying to access  \\N01APW280\d$, which is an administrative share and can only be accessed from under an account that has admin privileges on N01APW280.

Comment: I will find out which account it uses. But is there other way to copy file using a different account from the batch file?

Comment: This is the error with xcopy.Could Not Find D:\Hyperion\ERPI_Actuals_Load\Logs\PLPLAN.LOG
Invalid drive specification
The system cannot find the file specified.
The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: [But is there other way to copy file using a different account from the batch file?] -- I don't think so.